# Error generated in Hibernate Query for one specific property

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

We have made an generic search client on the project I work on.
Its a simple search plug-in that allows us to search on properties of an entity.

ex:

```
public class Movie {
    private String id;
    private String director;
    private String title;

    //set-getters
}
```

If we need to find a specific movie we can do stuff like:

```
movie.title='some title'
movie.title='some title' and director='bob'
```

If at some point in time we add a property X.
We can do:

```
movie.X='Y'
```

Without any code changes in our search solution.

This is working very well for us (for the basic searches) but now i ran into an problem. One of our entities has an property called "properties" and when we try to search on this an error is thrown..

```
"org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: generatedAlias1 near line 1, column 149 [select generatedAlias0 from N as generatedAlias1, S as generatedAlias0 where ( N.properties is null ) and ( N.id=S.node )]
```

The generated query works if i run it on my local DB, when I use the search end-point, it fails. Properties is a String field on the entity and VARCHAR in DB.

Any idea what went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed 'properties' to 'options'.. seems properties is a reserved word in the underlying query building libs